# Header title has a string addition and ignores one of the parameters when I run it remotely

Tags: string, null, string-concatenation, remote-execution

I have the following problem:
one member of the header row is an addition of strings like this:

```
"Amount (" + ContextHelper.GetLocalCurrency().ToString + ")"
```

in order to show, in case of us local currency:

> Amount (US)

it works fine when I run this locally, whether if I do it in my PC hitting the localhost or if I run locally the VM through a Remote Desktop Connection, also hitting the localhost.

But when I try hitting the service that is running in the VM from my PC (as the client will), the member of the header row only shows

> "Amount ()"

meaning `ContextHelper.GetLocalCurrency().ToString` is returning NULL.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What programming language and execution environment are you using? Is this C#? Java? VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this problem, a symbol `$` in that string was giving Visual Studio a hard time when trying to understand the currency as I was trying to show:

```
Amount(US$)
```

When I took away the `$` it works fine.